# Capybara::Poltergeist::InvalidSelector on element with id and class

Tags: capybara, poltergeist

I have code like this:

```
<td class="activities" id="3">
  <a id="3" class="btn add_activity" href="#">+</a>
</td>
```

And I want to click on the `+` link. The resulting form is opened with javascript, so I need Poltergeist to click on it. But it returns an error:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::InvalidSelector:
       The browser raised a syntax error while trying to evaluate css selector ".activities#28"
```

This is my test:

```
it "can open form", js: true do
  within(".activities#28") do
    click_link "+"
  end
end
```

So why it can't find the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here

1. Your CSS selector ".activities#28" is technically illegal.  This is because an id identifier in a CSS selector cannot start with a digit unless it is escaped.  To fix that your CSS selector would need to become `.activities#\32 8`
2. Once fixed it won't match the HTML you've shown, because the HTML shown has an id of "3" not "28"
3. Your HTML shown has two elements with the same id ("3").  That's illegal HTML since ids are required to be unique on the page.  Are you trying to store an id of a record that needs to be tied to that element on the page?  If so it could be in a data attribute instead (which would change your CSS selector too) - although storing the same multiple times doesn't make a lot of sense either.

   ```
   <td class="activities" data-id="3">
     <a class="btn add_activity" href="#" data-id="3">+</a>
   </td>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer! I will change the ID's so they follow web standards.